# Sending data from JavaScript to PHP using fetch API

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

I am trying to pass the screen width value from client side to server using fetch API because I want to make some changes from server side. But the var_dump function displays null. As well as var_dump($_POST).

Index.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $clientsize = json_decode($data, true);
    var_dump($clientsize);
    //echo $clientsize["width"];
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>API</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
const resizeobserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    let width = entry.borderBoxSize?.[0].inlineSize;

    if (typeof width === 'number' && width !== 0) {

    let clientWith = {"width":`${width}`};

    fetch("index.php", {
      "method":"POST",
      "headers":{
          "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8"
      },
      "body":JSON.stringify(clientWith)
    })

    }
   }
});
resizeobserver.observe(document.body);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if(isset($_POST)` will always be true whether you posted data or not. It always _exists_, but it's empty unless data was posted. So because of that you'll see the var_dump output when you first load your page, which has nothing to do with what gets subsequently sent in your fetch() request. On the other hand, your JS code makes no attempt to retrieve the response to the fetch() request, so you'll never see that output, unless you use your browser's Network tool to look at it manually.

Comment: As an aside...why does your PHP code need to know the screen width? I can't think of a reason why it would need to care (unless you are collecting some usage analytics or something??)

Comment: Normally you tackle this sort of issue via Responsive Design using CSS media queries. It's unclear why the server would need to be involved, unless there is a specific reason which cannot be solved by CSS

Comment: Definitely use CSS for this. Any other solution involves actual hell and will outdate.

Comment: I need to toggle some HTML tags that contain php blocks . And therefore, I can't do this on the client side

Comment: Not really. Just have php render all of it, and use CSS to control what is visible in different scenarios. Or, consider whether you actually _need_ different php blocks for different screens sizes - why does the screen size require you to change what php outputs? If you're using php to change the html content, consider whether a better, responsive-designed layout to begin with would actually solve the problem more efficiently.